# calculating a variable using loop over a multdimensional array python

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

I have tried to calculate a variable from a 3D array. The thing is: I have latitude and longitude in my grid, I want to measure the kinetic energy in a volume element. For that, I need the volume which is my depth x lat x lon. However, my lon and lat are variable which means I have to subtract i+1 from i to know exactly what the distance is. Thus, I have tried the following:

```
# the total length is var[32,327,899]

for i in range(1,328,1):
    for j in range(1,900,1):
        for k in range(1,33,1):
            j_dis=((lat[i+1,j]-lat[i,j])*1852.)/(1/60.) #distance from i to i+1 in meters
            i_dis=((lon[i,j+1]-lon[i,j])*1852.)/(1/60.) #distance from i to i+1 in meters
            z_dis=(zz[k+1,i,j]-zz[k,i,j])
            # Volume 
            vol[k,i,j]=i_dis*j_dis*z_dis
```

However, it doesn't work and I keep getting the following error:

**IndexError: index 899 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 899**

I know it is related about the size of my matrix but how can I subtract i+1 from i to get the value?

If anyone helped me I would appreciate it.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first index in a Python array is 0, so you need to change your range() statements like this:

```
for i in range(326):
    for j in range(898):
        for k in range(31):
            j_dis=((lat[i+1,j]-lat[i,j])*1852.)/(1/60.) #distance from i to i+1 in meters
            i_dis=((lon[i,j+1]-lon[i,j])*1852.)/(1/60.) #distance from i to i+1 in meters
            z_dis=(zz[k+1,i,j]-zz[k,i,j])
        # Volume 
        vol[k,i,j]=i_dis*j_dis*z_dis
```

I started the range at 0, and since you're subtracting two consecutive indices, I lowered the upper value to (size - 1), so that you don't exceed your array bounds.  And just so you know, `range(n)` generates values from 0 to n-1.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it seems it does the thing I was trying to do.